# TSQL IF appears to randomly execute code from wrong logic branch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, sql-server-2019

I have an idempotent script that brings different database deployments up to the latest revision.  The column referenced in the code is actually deleted in a future release, so in order to preserve the script's validity I check if the column exists before executing the statement.  I noticed some unexpected behaviour whereby the IF logic branches seem to intermittently execute when the condition is false.

### Basic example

```
IF (1 = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Adding data'; -- Never printed
    END
GO
```

### Testing the logic branch

```
IF (1 = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Adding data';                       -- Never printed
        RAISERROR('One never equals zero', 16, 1); -- Never raised
    END
GO
```

### Added data modification code

```
IF (1 = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Adding data';                                            -- Never printed
        RAISERROR('One never equals zero', 16, 1);                      -- Never raised
        INSERT INTO [tbl_Users] ( NonExistentColumn ) VALUES ( 'Bar' ); -- Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6; Invalid column name 'NonExistentColumn'.
    END
GO
```

Why does this happen?  Particularly, why are the `PRINT` and `RAISERROR` lines correctly ignored but the `INSERT` still executes, even though the entire logic branch should be ignored?

Comment: This is a compile error, *not* run time error. The compilation of the batch fails, due to the attempt to reference a column that doesn't exist, and thus the **entire** batch isn't run. The `IF` is never reached as *no SQL* is run; this is why you don't get your `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` as they were never run (and neither was the `INSERT`).

Comment: Adding to what @Larnu mentioned, you would need to execute the `INSERT` using dynamic SQL to avoid the compilation error in the outer scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your statements are run, it isn't skipping the `PRINT` and `RAISERROR` and going to the `INSERT INTO`, instead the entire batch fails due to a compilation error.

Despite some beliefs, T-SQL is *parsed* and validated before it is executed, and if the statement isn't valid then the entire batch won't be run; this is why when you have a syntax error, for example, none of the statements are run.

Here you have an invalid column reference, the column `NonExistentColumn` in the table `[YourDefaultSchema].tbl_Users` doesn't exist. Although SQL Server does have some deferred object validation, columns against objects that *exist* are not one of them. As such, when you ask for your batch to be executed, the parser checks to see table `[YourDefaultSchema].tbl_Users` has a column `NonExistentColumn`, and when it finds it doesn't, it raises an "Invalid Column Name" error.

If the table itself did not exist, then this error would not occur. For example, take the following batches:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn int);
GO
PRINT N'First Batch Starts';    
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT N'Entered first IF.';
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (AnotherColumn)
    VALUES(1);
END;
PRINT N'First Batch Ends';    
GO
PRINT N'Second Batch Starts';    
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT N'Entered second IF.';
    INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable (AnotherColumn)
    VALUES(1);
END;
PRINT N'Second Batch Ends';
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

In the messages pane of SSMS you will get the following:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'AnotherColumn'.
Second Batch Starts
Second Batch Ends
```

Notice that none of the `PRINT` statements from the first batch print, as the batch isn't run, however, in the second batch they are, as the validation of the column is deferred till that statement would be run (and it's never run, so no error occurs).

If you wanted to reference a potentially non-existent column on an existing object, defer the statement's validation using `sys.sp_executesql`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (SomeColumn int);
GO
PRINT N'Third Batch Starts';    
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT N'Entered first IF.';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (AnotherColumn) VALUES(1);';
END;
PRINT N'Third Batch Ends';    
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

This simply prints the following:

```
Third Batch Starts
Third Batch Ends
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8983657f7152f6b96789ec4605e992f)

Comment: Thank you, that's really interesting.  I think I was thrown here because it appears that the same parsing routine does **not check that the tables exist**, e.g. `INSERT INTO [tbl_NonExistentTable] ( Foo ) VALUES ( 'Bar' );` parses and avoids the issue, which is not particularly intuitive IMHO.  Is there a reason for that do you know?

Comment: Even more strange is that for my 'broken' code, the SSMS *"Parse (CTRL+F5)"* function DOES parse it okay.  It only fails upon execution.  I'm somewhat baffled by this.

Comment: Parsing the query checks the syntax is valid, @EvilDr , not if it compiles (or more specifically if the column exists).

Comment: Related question on [dba.se]: [SQL Server Management Studio: how to parse stored procedure code and check if table columns exist?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/sql-server-management-studio-how-to-parse-stored-procedure-code-and-check-if-ta)